# Usage of Heroku with Django

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm currently learning Django and getting a decent grasp of it.   I know you can start the server with python manage.py runserver.  But then there is also heroku ps:scale web=1 followed by heroku open to open the web page at the subdomain you chose on the host herokuapp.com.  What is the point of using heroku vs just runserver?  When it comes time to deploy to production is that what heroku is used for as I read it was for deployment?  What is exactly is heroku used for and what are the reasons?  When creating a professional django web site/application is heroku required or just very useful?  If so why?  I don't really understand the reason for using heroku.  And I'm curious what the best practices are for django and whether they include using or not using heroku.

Aside from the heroku question, what are the best practices for django as far as setting a domain name and such (other than the herokuapp.com subdomain name) and also as far as what other components/software solutions are worth using with django?

One of the things I'm working on is an FTP portal on the website that people can login to and upload files.  Does django have plugins/python modules for such a thing or must it be done custom?  Which brings me to my final question, What kind of addons/modules does django offer to avoid reinventing the wheel when implementing a django website/app's certain features?

The tutorial I'm following: http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_orm/README.html

has helped me get a grasp on django, but I'm  curious about the more advanced parts of it.  Such as custom modules, custom styling, custom scripts (whether they are js or strictly python).

If someone could point me in the right direction or offer any suggestions it would be much appreciated.  The tutorial has me using the modules: dj-database-url, whitenoise, gunicorn, python-dateutil, psycopg2                                                 , requests.  I know what some of them do, but what is the purpose of psycopg2, whitenoise, dateutil, and dj-database,url?  Are there any other modules worth using?

Sorry for the wall of questions, but I'm trying to understand django as best I can so that I can do a correct assessment when putting together a django project.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT, final questions:

1) Also when i used heroku they gave me a subdomain at herokuapps.com Can I set my own URL and still use heroku?

2) And last but not least, heroku makes you register and gives you a subdomain on herokuapp.com Is there a way to use heroku with your own domain rather than the one they give you? Is there a specific way to do it?

EDIT 2:

When I do runserver it works fine, but when i run it with heroku  ps:scale web=1 and then heroku open it opens but only shows the title at the top of the page, and no content.  Not sure exactly why that is.  Can someone explain the difference between runserver and heroku ps:scale web=1 followed by heroku open??

Comment: I don't see what's confusing you. Heroku is a server where you can host your site. You can't run a production website off your laptop, after all.

Comment: What confuses me is whether or not to use heroku in production rather than  just using the runserver command.  Which is better to use?

Comment: Also when i used heroku they gave me a subdomain at herokuapps.com  Can I set my own URL and still use heroku?

Comment: But that question about runserver makes no sense at all. How could you use runserver - running on your own laptop - for production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `python manage.py runserver` is only for development. Never use it in production.
2. **Heroku** makes it super easy to deploy your Django code. You only need some configs and `git push heroku master`. But it's not the only way to deploy your code. You can also set up a server with a webserver like Nginx, Gunicorn as WSGI server, and a database of your choice. To set things up, you need to know something about Linux and the command line.
3. So if you don't know how to set up a server, Heroku can be very useful.
4. [Heroku supports custom domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains), and it's easy to set up.
5. As Mikeec3 mentioned, ["Two Scoops of Django"](http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-6) is a very good read.
6. If you are looking for django packages, [www.djangopackages.com](https://www.djangopackages.com/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

psycopg2 is for postgresql usage with your  app. White noise allows you to serve your staticfiles without nginx if using gunicorn. Requests is an easy to use urllib2 library with pythonic calls to work with apis from other websites.

If you want to do some testing with say facebook logins Heroku is a great place to go to, especially if you need a url outside of localhost.

My suggestion is you read Two scoops of Django http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-6

It goes over alot of best practices and serves as a great tutorial after polls. I suggest also incorporating django-bower into your project. Ill list a few great things to add.

Django Bower: https://github.com/nvbn/django-bower - Helps organize static files

Crispy Forms : https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms - Great form rendering, great with bootstrap

Django Rest Framework: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework - REST APIs

These are just to start, there's alot to learn.

Comment: Just a question, styling the django site. Do i do this with just CSS?  Is JS involved at all?  I would guess no since we have Python as scripting language

Comment: You're still building a webapp, python is just your backend language. It can help render a lot of what you want but with anything that is user friendly javascript helps alot. Remember to keep everything organized!

Comment: Ill accept the answer if you can answer my final question:  whats the diff between doinbg python manage.py runserver and heroku ps:scale web=1 followed by heroku open ?  in production which would you use ?

Comment: And last but not least, heroku makes you register and gives you a subdomain on herokuapp.com  Is there a way to use heroku with your own domain rather than the one they give you?  Is there a specific way to do it?

Comment: Ok so the main difference is that you have a subdomain to test with, take Facebook authentication for instance you can't test it locally anymore. In production I would rather have my own domain and AWS since scaling heroku is pretty expensive. Runserver is a testing server by django which they say isn't meant for production. Also you can buy a domain from namecheap or such and use with a heroku deployment. Like I said i recommend amazon ec2 over heroku for production due to costs but that's an opinion.